# Can't use multiple instances of findall

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am getting an `index range error` when I try to use multiple `findall`s, but if I just use one, then the code works.

```
from re import findall
news = open('download7.html', 'r')

title = findall('<item>[^<]+<title>(.*)</title>', news.read())
link = findall('<item>[^<]+<title>[^<]+</title>[^<]+<link>(.*)</link>', news.read())
description = findall('<!\[CDATA\[[^<]+<p>(.*)</p>', news.read())
pubdate = findall('<pubDate>([^<]+)</pubDate>', news.read())
image_regex = findall('url="([^"]+627.jpg)', news.read())
print(image_regex[0])
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you don't have any empty lists/Nones after first call? Could you please check this?
Why you don't assign news.read() to variable?
IMHO using regexes for searching stuff inside pure html is always bad idea. Did you try to use dedicated modules for xml-like structures? Should be faster and easier because there you can use simple xpaths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to use regex because it's kinda like homework so i can't use anything else. It works after assigning news.read() to a variable but can you explain it to me that why it worked after assigning news.read() to a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.read()` on a file object reads all remaining data from the file, and leaves the file pointer at the end of the file (so subsequent calls to `.read()` return the empty string).

Cache the file contents once, and reuse it:

```
from re import findall

with open('download7.html', 'r') as news:
    newsdata = news.read()

title = findall('<item>[^<]+<title>(.*)</title>', newsdata)
link = findall('<item>[^<]+<title>[^<]+</title>[^<]+<link>(.*)</link>', newsdata)
description = findall('<!\[CDATA\[[^<]+<p>(.*)</p>', newsdata)
pubdate = findall('<pubDate>([^<]+)</pubDate>', newsdata)
image_regex = findall('url="([^"]+627.jpg)', newsdata)
print(image_regex[0])
```

Note: You could re-read from the file object by seeking back to the beginning after each read (calling `news.seek(0)`), but that's far less efficient when you need the complete file data over and over.

Comment: Note: You really out to be using an XML parser, and even if you do use regexes, use raw strings for the patterns. But your problem in this case had nothing to do with regexes or parsing, you just misused files.